# How to grab object values from spreadsheet to paste to html input form

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

HTML part I want to paste to

```
  <div>
    <label for="entryRef">Ref</label><button id="FindByRef">Find</button>
    <input id="entryRef" list="EntryRef">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="entryDate">Date</label>
    <input id="entryDate" type="date">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="entryName">To/From</label>
    <input id="entryName" list="Name_list">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="entryDescription">Description</label>
    <textarea id="entryDescription"></textarea>
  </div>
```

HTML script part, I'm stuck with this part. I ran and nothing paste to them, Please help!

```
function refSelect(ref) {
  document.getElementById("entryDate").value = ref.date
  document.getElementById("entryName").value = ref.name
  document.getElementById("entryDescription").value = ref.desc
} //**** to paste the data to HTML, need to fix this part? ****

function entryGet() {
  var refSelected = document.getElementById("entryRef").value

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refSelect).getEntry(refSelected)
}

document.getElementById("FindByRef").addEventListener("click",entryGet)
```

Google Script part. I get the data from, as an object

```
function getEntry(refSelected) {

  var filtered = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("Core!A4:F").getValues().filter(r => r[0] === refSelected)

  return {
    ref : filtered[0],
    date : filtered[1],
    name : filtered[2],
    desc : filtered[3],
    acc : filtered[4],
    amt : filtered[5]
  }
}
```

The sample Spreadsheet [Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 1] to open the form
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lpXqW7-VXBFPjtzXIzjUHa9p2uTFJrl67CO6AH2kKoQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance

Comment: getRangeByName() is for named ranges..

Comment: Thank you I should have noticed this, and I fixed as @Tanaike's answer below - yet still won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, `getEntry` of Google Apps script side has an issue.

  - If `Core!A4:F` is the a1Notation, please modify `getRangeByName` to `getRange`.
  - `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("Core!A4:F").getValues().filter(r => r[0] === refSelected)` returns 2 dimensional array. So in your situation, when the search value is the unique value, please add `[0]` to it.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var filtered = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("Core!A4:F").getValues().filter(r => r[0] === refSelected)
```

To:

```
var filtered = SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getRange("Core!A4:F")
  .getValues()
  .filter(r => r[0] === refSelected)[0];
```

And, if the column "B" is the date object, also please modify as follows.

From:

```
  return {
    ref : filtered[0],
    date : filtered[1],
    name : filtered[2],
    desc : filtered[3],
    acc : filtered[4],
    amt : filtered[5]
  }
```

To:

```
  return {
    ref : filtered[0],
    date : `${filtered[1].getFullYear()}-${("0" + (filtered[1].getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${("0" + filtered[1].getDate()).slice(-2)}`,  // Modified
    name : filtered[2],
    desc : filtered[3],
    acc : filtered[4],
    amt : filtered[5]
  }
```

#### Note:

- If `Core!A4:F` is the named range, please use `getRangeByName("Core!A4:F")`.
- When you open the HTML using Web Apps, after you modified the script, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: Thank you I should have noticed. I fixed this part, but the data are still not showing

Comment: @zummontt Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, in order to correctly understanding your situation, when you provided the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue, it will help to think of your current issue. Because in my environment, when `filtered` returns the correct value, `refSelect` works. How about this?

Comment: @zummontt Although I'm not sure about your Spreadsheet, I added one more modification point. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I somehow got the sample Spreadsheet work :D, but my main won't. Must be my massive code. Thanks a lot. anyways I'll share the sample Spreadsheet and I'm trying fix from it now

Comment: @zummontt Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `but my main won't.`. By the way, when I tested your shared Spreadsheet which reflected my modification points, it seems that when `Ref` is set and click `Find` button, the values are retrieved. When my modification points are not reflected, no values are returned. So what is your current issue?

Comment: The values are retrieved correctly, after I recreate the shared sheets. But my main file somehow still does nothing. I'll get to you later after I found out what's really going on with my file

Comment: @zummontt Thank you for replying. The modified script worked for the sample Spreadsheet. But it doesn't work for your actual Spreadsheet. I understood like this. I apologize that I couldn't propose the more modification points by estimating your actual Spreadsheet. It was found that the modified script which reflected my proposed modification points worked for your sample. Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, I believe the modification points also leads to the solution for your actual Spreadsheet.

Comment: it works now, silly me I forgot to put `.value` after `document.getElementById("entryDescription")` And a little more thing please. About the retrieving, it retrieves date, -1 day. Did this correct to you when you click `Find`? Is it because my time zone?

Comment: @zummontt Thank you for replying. In your case, I understood that the year, month and day are used. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Amazing code right there, I learn a lot of things. Thank you so much. But `...filtered[1].getMonth() + 1` is still text, how to convert to number again please - in this structure. Because of searching if search which date is ..Feb.. - month should be 2, but it return 11 Month ..Jan.. works fine

Comment: @zummontt  Thank you for replying. I have to apologize. I noticed the modification point. The addition of the number became the addition of the string. So I modified the script. Please check it.